Does rage, or any of the barbarian level 3 paths, boost unarmed strikes?
Mainly I'm asking in case I get thrown into a situation similar to the Tournament of Power from Dragon Ball Super, or most of the other tournaments in Z and Super, where I can't use weapons. Is there a path that boosts unarmed strike when raging?

Is this better at getting straight to the point and showing why I'm asking?

Rage and Path of the Beast, Berserker and Zealot
Unarmed strikes are considered melee weapon attacks, so rage would boost unarmed damage for any barbarian.
Path of the Beast will give you a natural weapon while raging. Technically not unarmed strikes, but it would give you a weapon to use when you don't have any normal weapons.
Path of the Berserker lets you make an additional unarmed attack as a bonus action.
Path of the Zealot's Divine Fury applies to unarmed strikes which adds 1d6 + half your barbarian level as radiant or necrotic damage to the first target you hit each turn.

Thank you, I wasn't sure if unarmed strikes counted as melee weapon attacks. Do they also count for path of the giant's level 6 feature for the extra elemental damage?

No, because your fists aren't weapons. It's a weird thing in 5e where unarmed attacks are melee weapon attacks, but not melee attacks with a weapon.

Alright, thanks.
